# Division of a list to two sublists based on regex

Tags: python, list

I have a list of the format `l = ["1","2","3*","5","9*","10*"]`. What is the best way to divide this list to two sublists based on regex `.*\*`? The resulting sublists should look as follows:

```
sub1 = ["1","2","5"]
sub2 = ["3*","9*","10*"]
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `3*`. What do you **actually** have? `[1, 2, 33, 4, 99999]` ?

Comment: Just fixed a description. It's actually a list of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for regex to solve this..

```
sub1 = [s for s in l if not s.endswith('*')]
sub2 = [s for s in l if s.endswith('*')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just split the string on commas into an array, then just separate the array.
You didn't tag a language, but in java the string.split(",") would give you an array of strings. Then loop over those strings and put the elements into two different lists or reformat the string.

Comment: It's Python. I was hoping there is something smarter than iterating through the list and checking each element for a regex match myself.

Answer (score 0):

Must you use the regexp package?  If not:

```
sub1 = [_ for _ in l if '*' not in _]
sub2 = [_ for _ in l if '*' in _]
```

If you need to derive sub2 from l and sub1:

```
sub2 = list(set(l) - set(sub1))
```

Comment: But I think performance of `sub2 = list(set(l) - set(sub1))` over `sub2 = [_ for _ in l if '*' in _]` is worse as we need also to transform lists to sets, isn't it?

Comment: Correct.  I thought that perhaps you had a restriction in a programming assignment, and wanted to cover that possibility.  Also, the list=>set=>list conversion is the fastest way to perform list difference.